# how to retrieve the queries used in a store procedure through jdbc

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have been calling a stored procedure through jdbc and i have a requirement that the queries used in that stored procedure should be displayed on console.

can you suggest a code to retieve the queries used in the stored procedure from the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can see previously executed queries using the `v$sql` view...

```
select * from v$session join v$sql using (sql_id)
```

That's not a history of all statements, though...

Comment: will that apply to stored procedures also?

Comment: It doesn't matter how a statement is executed to end up in the cursor cache.